# Setting dir/page/page redirect distinct from dir/page?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some `.htaccess` rewrite rules like the below:

```
RewriteRule name/john item.php?id=1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule name/jill item.php?id=2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

On the above pages, I want to link to something like `name/john/profile`. I've tried the below rules:

```
RewriteRule name/john/profile profile.php?id=1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule name/jill/profile profile.php?id=2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But clicking these links redirects to `item.php`, not `profile.php`.

Are deeper rules not possible or am I missing a flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^name/john/?$ item.php?id=1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^name/jill/?$ item.php?id=2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^name/john/profile/?$ profile.php?id=1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^name/jill/profile/?$ profile.php?id=2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I like to add `/?` because after that works with or without final `/`